# Django Rest Framework Foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here's what I have:

Python 3.4
Django 1.8
RestFramework: 3.1.3

models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Order(models.Model):
  referenece = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

Serializer

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Order
```

I created also the right view and udpate the router. When I display http://localhost:8000/order/

It works fine, it propose me an empty list for customer. As soon as I have add one customer I got:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /api/order/

Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "customer-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

I tried to add in order serializer meta regarding the documentation

```
    extra_kwargs = {
        'customer': {'lookup_field': 'company_name'}
    }
```

but it's the same.

Any idea what I did wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please show your URLs and customer-detail view.

Comment: make sure you register the view[Set] in your `urls.py` with `router.register(r'customers', views.CustomerViewSet)`. [Here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) you find the default names the framework uses. As you can see `customer-detail` is one of such defaults.

Comment: I don't have a customer-detail view.

Comment: I checked, I also have a link OneToOne with User object and I don't need to add User to the urls.py (not present in urls). If I add the CustomerViewSet it will propose me to add a customer also with the Order and fix the issue but I don't want to add a customer, I want to link an existing customer. Sorry if I'm not clear enougth.